# ajax toolkit combobox appears on fixed position controls (menu)

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a fixed position menu in my master page. Everything was going ok until I noticed that the ajax toolking combo box appears on the menu when I scroll down.

When I scroll down controls disappear under the menu.

[My menu is Blue and Black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCe3w.png)

You can see the combo box goes on the menu instead of disappearing behind.

[After I have scrolled down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpVAv.png)
this is how I fixed the position of the menu:

position: fixed;

How can I fix it???, please

Answer (score 1):

I added Z-position=10000 to the Menu. Fixed.